# SSD secure erase on RAID card (Linux)

Tags: linux, ssd, centos, hdparm

My SSD RAID write performance has slowed dramatically from when it was new, so I want to use the ATA "secure erase" command to restore it.  From my research, this is the best way to restore performance, as it's a lower level erase than writing zeroes with dd.

These drives are Samsung 850 Pro on an LSI 9361 RAID card.  I tried setting it to JBOD mode so that the OS can see each individual drive.
Samsung Magician boot disk cannot see the drives unless they are connected to the motherboard.  Adding insult to injury, it makes you reboot after erasing each drive, so this is a very time-consuming process.

I try `hdparm` version 9.43 and it works if I connect the drives to the motherboard, but it fails if the drives are in JBOD mode on the RAID card:

```
$ sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-set-pass PASS /dev/sdc
security_password="PASS"    
/dev/sdc:
Issuing SECURITY_SET_PASS command, password="PASS", user=user, mode=high

$ sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-erase PASS /dev/sdc
security_password="PASS"
/dev/sdc:
 Issuing SECURITY_ERASE command, password="PASS", user=user
ERASE_PREPARE: Invalid argument
```

I do see that `storcli64` has a secure-erase feature, but I can't get it to work:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
/c0/e252/s0 Failure   255 Secure erase is not allowed on this drive. 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `hdparm` should work correctly if you connect the drives directly to the MB's SATA ports.

Comment: Probably, but I would really like to avoid that.  The SSDs are in an IcyDock hot swap cage, so this would mean removing each one, unracking the chassis, and connecting to the motherboard one at a time.